# Obtener los datos del comprador con redsys

Tags: php

estoy implementando un tpv virtual con redsys. Solo me falta obtener los datos del comprador en la url de notificacion (`DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTURL`). He obtenido el total de la compra con esta orden: `$codigoRespuesta = $miObj->getParameter("Ds_Amount");`
pero los datos del comprador imprescindibles como el email, direccion y nombre no se como obtenerlos.
este es el codigo de la pagina de notificacion:

```
<html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <?php


        include 'apiRedsys.php';
        include 'functions.php';
        // Se crea Objeto
        $miObj = new RedsysAPI;


    if (!empty( $_POST ) ) {//URL DE RESP. ONLINE
                        
                        $version = $_POST["Ds_SignatureVersion"];
                        $datos = $_POST["Ds_MerchantParameters"];
                        $signatureRecibida = $_POST["Ds_Signature"];
                        

                        $decodec = $miObj->decodeMerchantParameters($datos);    
                        $kc = 'sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7'; //Clave recuperada de CANALES
                        $firma = $miObj->createMerchantSignatureNotif($kc,$datos);  

                                        $codigoRespuesta = $miObj->getParameter("Ds_Amount");
                                        //$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
                                        //$email_to = $customer->getEmail();
                                        
                        echo PHP_VERSION."<br/>";
                        echo $firma."<br/>";
                        echo $signatureRecibida."<br/>";
                        if ($firma === $signatureRecibida){
                            echo "FIRMA OK";email("luilli.guillan@gmail.com","holas",$codigoRespuesta);
                        } else {
                            echo "FIRMA KO";
                        }
        }
        else{
            if (!empty( $_GET ) ) {//URL DE RESP. ONLINE
                    
                $version = $_GET["Ds_SignatureVersion"];
                $datos = $_GET["Ds_MerchantParameters"];
                $signatureRecibida = $_GET["Ds_Signature"];
                    
            
                $decodec = $miObj->decodeMerchantParameters($datos);
                $kc = 'sq7HjrUOBfKmC576ILgskD5srU870gJ7'; //Clave recuperada de CANALES
                $firma = $miObj->createMerchantSignatureNotif($kc,$datos);
            
                        $codigoRespuesta = $miObj->getParameter("Ds_Amount");
                        //$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
                        //$email_to = $customer->getEmail();
                        
                if ($firma === $signatureRecibida){
                    echo "FIRMA OK" ;email("luilli.guillan@gmail.com","holas",$codigoRespuesta);
                } else {
                    echo "FIRMA KO";
                }
            }
            else{
                die("No se recibió respuesta");
            }
        }

    ?>
        
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

En la respuesta de Redsys no van a aparecer los datos que refieres del cliente si en la petición de pago no los has incluido previamente. Dicho esto, creo que tienes dos opciones:

1. Obtenerlos desde tu back-end de alguna forma. Desconozco si tienes implementado algún mecanismo para esto, aunque por lo que veo en estas líneas comentadas:

```html
    //$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    //$email_to = $customer->getEmail();
```

... es lo que tratas de hacer de alguna forma.

2. Incluir en la llamada al proceso de pago datos personalizados que después quieras recuperar en la respuesta. Los puedes incluir en el parámetro DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTDATA del objeto de la petición que redsys habilita especialmente para este efecto:

```html
$miObj->setParameter("DS_MERCHANT_MERCHANTDATA", $email.','.$idpedido);
//Aquí puedes incluir la información que necesites. Seguramente los datos de cliente los tienes en el propio formulario y puedes capturarlos.
```